# SSAS Calculated Member Based on Dimension Attribute

Tags: ssas

I'm trying to create a calculated measure that returns the converted value of an amount to Euro : i have the measure  [Measures].[Montant] in my fact table but i need to use a dimension attribute [Taux Change].[Taux Euro] that represents the conversion rate.

My calculated measure should basically be something like :

[converted_amount] = [Measures].[Montant]*[Taux Change].[Taux Euro]

My problem is that this new calculated measure returns Blank.

Could you please help me find the appropriate MDX code to use in my case.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include your actual MDX Calc

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that, since you say [Taux Change].[Taux Euro] is a *dimension attribute* rather than a single calculated measure, it's returning a blank value because the member being returned from that dimension is the default member (usually the ALL member).

Try testing with a single calculated measure:

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.TauxEuroTest AS 0.91 (or whatever number you like)
```

then use Measures.TauxEuroTest instead of [Taux Change].[Taux Euro] in your calculated member and see if that works.

As GregGalloway says, it's hard to definitely answer this without more detail: what does [Taux Change].[Taux Euro] actually mean in terms of the dimension structure?  Is it pointing to member [Taux Euro] of dimension [Taux Change]